# My chrome console log filter not working/buggy

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

Since around 2 weeks ago, my console filter starts to filter out even matching text. Tried restarting, is currently on the latest chrome version, also tried to restore settings, nothing. Searched on the web too didn't really find anything similar... I am banging my head against the wall right now if anyone has a lead, please... (Apparently one of my coworkers also starts to have this issue recently... )

Edit1: So played with a couple versions of chrome more. I am current on 95.0.4638.69. Tried beta version 96.x, same issue. Tried chromium  94.x, it works all fine! Haven't got a chance to try chrome 94.x as I dont' want to uninstall my chrome yet. But yeah I am leaning towards that the 95.x updates may break it, though I haven't seen any official info regarding it.

Comment: I see the same in edge, things I used to filter on are no longer working

Comment: appears it may be related to this: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-95/#properties

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Same issue on Chrome 95.0.4638.69 (latest as of 9 Nov 2021)

Workaround I'm using at present is to use `Regular Expression` format in place of standard filter string e.g. `test` -> `/test/`, then it works just the same

To filter by multiple strings separate with a pipe (OR) character `/test|another/`, and add an empty string pipe at the end to quickly clear filtering without deleting the filter `/test|another|/`

Comment: Great workaround - Didn't know we could use Regex on chrome filters! Does anyone know about a ticket tracking the real solution to this problem?